# API call example for Google Keep - unable to authorize

Tags: typescript, google-api, google-api-client

I am trying to create a set of typescript functions to call google keep API (https://developers.google.com/keep/api/reference/rest/v1/notes/list). I have created a service account and granted domain delegation for the keep scope to it for the given email address.
As per this doc https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#httprest I have created a function to generate API token like this

```
import { JWT } from 'google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtclient';
import { google } from 'googleapis';
import { admin_directory_v1 } from 'googleapis';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const generateAccessToken = async (email: string, key: string, impersonationEmail: string) => {
    const client = new JWT({
        email: email,
        key: key,
        subject: impersonationEmail,
        scopes: [ 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/keep' ],
    });
    
    const accessToken = await client.getAccessToken();
    return accessToken.token;
};

const getKeepNotes = async (accessToken: string) => {
    
    const response = await fetch(`https://keep.googleapis.com/v1/notes??access_token=${accessToken}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { Accept: 'application/json', },
      });
    if(!response.ok){

    }
};
const main= async () => {

    const originalDomain = 'domain.com';
    const originalEmail = 'service-account@mail';
    const originalKey = '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----PRIVATEKEY-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n';

    const users = await getUsers(originalDomain, originalEmail, originalKey);
    for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
       const accessToken = await generateAccessToken(originalEmail, originalKey, users[i].primaryEmail);
       const keep = await getKeepNotes(accessToken);
       console.log(keep);
    }

    return;
};
```

The problem is that the 'getKeepNotes' method return "Forbidden HttpCode 403" Error.

> We're sorry...... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can't process your request right now.

I am not sure what the issue is since all other Google SDK work without any issues
Any help or suggestions appreciated.

Comment: The access token should be provided as a header (`Authorization: Bearer {access_token}`) not part of the query string

Comment: All Google's services are supported by API Client Libraries, your life may be easier if you use the [JavaScript API Client Libraries](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client).

Comment: @DazWilkin as I understood js API client does not support impersonation (which I need and that is why I have set up a service account with the super admin account privileges) So that the actual users would not have to explicitly grant access to their data manually and I can do the data move in the background.

Comment: Interesting. I don't know but I'm surprised. DId you find it documented? Did the code work when you added the Authorization header?

Comment: Also adding access_token into a header did not solve it. I am trying to retrieve token like this:

const generateAccessToken = async (email: string, key: string, impersonationEmail: string) => {

    const client = new JWT({
        email: email,
        key: key,
        subject: impersonationEmail,
        scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/keep'],
    });

    const accessToken = await client.getAccessToken();
    return accessToken.token;
};

Comment: Re gapi I found some docs (related to the authorization here https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/start.md there is only either ApiKey (does not allow impersonation or access to private data) or OAuth2 client with explicit permission grants. I also looked in the code and there is no option to use service account's key or secret - hence no implicit  impersonation

Comment: I'm less familiar with JavaScript but it sounds as though you're confident the JWT construction and access token process is accurate (and it looks reasonable). I tried using [oauth2l](https://github.com/google/oauth2l#header) to generate Keep scoped credentials for my user account and I also get 403 from the method (`ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT`).

Comment: yeah, so, does this mean API is unusable at all ?

Comment: I don't know. You need to contact Google. If you don't have support, try filing on Google's public [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/)